# Daemon на MonoDevelop (C#)

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

Мне нужно написать аналог Windows Service под Linux на MonoDevelop, который будет запускаться/завершаться из-под другой программы (как дочерний процесс). Реально ли это сделать на C#?

Comment: если простой аналог WinService, то ни чего изобретать не нужно, пишете консольное приложение и "демонизируете", к C# это уже отношения не имеет. А вот по поводу запуска из под другой программы, это я не очень понял, но скорее всего как-то так же.

Comment: @rdorn если почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/129207/, то нужно форкнуть процесс и перевести его в фоновый режим (отделить его от TTY), чёт я сомневаюсь, что такое можно написать на `C#`.

Comment: @Bulson ну у меня под centos7 в виде демона живет автономное WebApi-приложение, и ничего, только развертывание немного сложнее, чем просто копирование в папочку полноценного web-сервера. Но тут все от конкретного дистрибутива еще зависит, вероятно.

Comment: @rdorn т.е. ваш демон прописан на запуск в `init.d`, висит, слушает порт и пишет в system log?

Comment: Для .NET Core есть решение из коробки - https://www.wintellect.com/creating-a-daemon-with-net-core-part-1/. Допускается ли в вашей ситуации использовать .NET Core?

Comment: @Bulson ну да, и не только в локальный, еще в ELK логи агрегирутся с нескольких инстансов

Comment: @rdorn, подскажите, как "демонизировать" приложение конкретно на Шарпе. Я просто в С# полный профан, так что для меня это неочевидно

Comment: Я же писал, к шарпу это отношения не имеет, а вот дистрибутив линукс вероятно значение имеет, делал под centos, будет ли работать тоже самое на другом - без понятия, там же целый зоопарк и каждый со "своим преферансом и барышнями"

Comment: @rdorn, если несложно, то можете описать процесс под CentOS, я попробую перенести на свой Lubuntu

Comment: Вот [тут](https://h1d3.org/posts/demonizatsiia-skriptov-i-prilozhenii.html) есть один из вариантов, может подойдет вам. Как только найду =) оно на рабочих серверах крутится

Comment: @rdorn, заранее благодарю

Comment: [Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/332920/) буквально строк 30 в конце, как собственно сделано у меня, не уверен, что делал прямо по этой статье, но очень похоже. А [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#monitor-the-app) оригинальная инструкция от MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации .net core есть [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#create-the-service-file). Официально, пример для Ubuntu 16.04, я использовал на Centos 7. Вероятно, будет работать на большинстве популярных дистрибутивов linux, но это я не проверял, стараюсь избегать зоопарка. В целом, такой подход позволяет "демонизировать" любое консольное приложение, главное чтобы оно работало с стандартным потоком вывода.

Тут приведу только необходимый минимум, подробности в документации по ссылке и документации вашего конкретного дистрибутива линукс (могут быть отличия, иногда существенные, ибо зоопарк)

Создайте файл определения службы.

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-helloapp.service

Пример файла службы для нашего приложения.

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/helloapp
#команда для запуска вашего приложения такая же, как при обычном запуске в консоли
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/helloapp/helloapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
#не забываем предварительно создать пользователя и выдать ему необходимые права
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Сохраните файл и включите службу.

> sudo systemctl enable kestrel-helloapp.service

Запустите службу и убедитесь, что она работает.

> sudo systemctl start kestrel-helloapp.service
>
> sudo systemctl status kestrel-helloapp.service

---

[Тут](https://h1d3.org/posts/demonizatsiia-skriptov-i-prilozhenii.html) есть вариант с использованием [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), но статья довольно старая, и сам я такой вариант не пробовал, хватило описанного, так что смотрите сами.

Comment: Спасибо, за интересную инфу.

Comment: @Bulson да я сам год назад не ожидал, что все так просто получится, а тут вон оно как =)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Comment: @r3pl1c4nt если подошло, можете поставить галочку под рейтингом ответа. Если кто-то напишет более подходящий вам ответ, ее можно будет переставить.

Comment: @rdorn, о'кей, готово